# kernel_task high cpu

Tags: mac-mini, ventura

MacMini with Apple M1 chip running ventura 13.5 have very high kernal_task cpu.

I opted for only 8gb memory and this is always under high memory pressure. I feel like my old mac mini almost worked better.

How do I find out what process is contributing to it?

It is frequently much higher than 40% just where I captured screen shot, you can see CPU time it is far and away higher than any other application

[image: high kernal_task]

Comment: 40% is 40% of 1 core. Your Mini CPU has 8 cores, so that's 5% of total CPU. What's your total CPU usage? (at the bottom). kernel_task is a special process that deals with lots of low-level functions: it often has stuff to do.

Comment: Is the Mini running hot, did you check for dust?

Comment: @nohillside I was thinking that if it were throttling for heat, it would be considerably higher.

Comment: Also much more complicated and not as clear cut on M1, as there's efficiency & performance cores doing different things at different speeds. A truer representation is often to see what's going on on the Energy tab.